# Como verificar se existe algum atributo nulo no objeto?

Tags: java, null

Tenho uma classe **Pessoa** e quero verificar se existe algum atributo nulo, qualquer um que seja pois não posso salvar uma **pessoa** com atributo nulo.
Quero evitar um monte de **if**. Há alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
public void salvar(Pessoa p) throws Exception {

    if (p.getNome() == null) {
        throw new Exception("Nome nulo");
    } else if (p.getIdade == null) {
        throw new Exception("Idade nula");
    } else if (p.getCorDosOlhos == null) {
        throw new Exception("CorDosOlhos nulo");
    }
}
```

Comment: A melhor forma é que os valores desses atributos seja passados no construtor. Assim é garantido que eles foram inicializados em cada um dos objectos instanciados. Ao mesmo tempo a classe só deverá disponibilizar *getters* para esses atributos de forma a manter o seu estando como válido.

Comment: Não possuo muito conhecimento sobre Java, mas tentou pesquisar se existe alguma de colocar um 'Required' nos atributos? No caso de C# possui o 'Required' que torna o campo obrigatório. Mas poderia tentar fazer o que o @ramaral sugeriu, o problema seria que o atributo iria com um valor padrão.

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho Para este caso não haveria "valor padrão": o nome da pessoa não muda, a cor dos olhos também não, no caso da idade o correcto é solicitar a data de nascimento e essa também não muda.

Comment: É claro que isso não evita o teste de nulo no construtor, mas julgo que é aí ele deve ser feito.

Comment: @ramaral desculpa, entendi errado sua resposta a princípio, mas agora acho que entendi sua resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já disse o ramaral em comentários, se precisa que todos os dados tenham algum valor, o ideal é que o tipo garanta isto por si só. Pode ser via construtor e métodos *setter* (fazendo validações ou tendo sua ausência) além de inicialização automática dos membros.

Se isso não é possível, se depende de contexto, ou seja, hora pode ter membros nulos, hora não pode, já pensou que tem dois problemas e talvez meraça dois tipos diferentes? Um deles permite o nulo e o outro não permite. Então em determinado momento pode usar um para criar o outro, e obviamente que o que não permite nulos falhará se não for inicializado propriamente.

Isso não resolve? Ok, você já achou a solução mais óbvia. E se deseja lançar exceções específicas para cada membro que falhar não tem soluções simples.

Se puder ter uma solução geral para qualquer membro que falhe, pode usar [reflexão](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). Com essa técnica pode varrer todos os membros de forma genérica e verificar os valores. Não é algo muito performático mas resolve na maioria dos casos. Se tiver casos diferentes (excepcionais) vai ter que tratar tudo isto.

Se precisar de performance pode usar um gerador de código para analisar a classe e criar um código que faça a verificação de todos os membros um por um de forma direta sem escrever o código para cada classe. Obviamente será necessário rodar uma ferramenta para gerar o código novo toda vez que alguém mexer na classe (isso pode ser automatizado também, óbvio).

Ainda é possível automatizar um pouco o processo, mesmo tendo tratamentos diferentes para cada membro. Isso exigirá um *framework* ou uma ferramenta mais complexa de geração de código. De qualquer forma os membros precisarão de [anotações](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) ou alguma outra forma de informar o que fazer com cada um deles.

Tudo vai depender de convenção para automatizar melhor.

Com uma pergunta tão genérica fica difícil dar uma solução mais específica.

Exemplo de reflexão:

```
for (Field field : Pessoa.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
        //faz alguma coisa aqui com field
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Reflection.java).

[Documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

[Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

[Pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112590/221800) sobre o assunto. [Outra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1526826/221800).

[Não sou fã do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Agradeço a todos, foram respostas que me ajudaram a formular melhor meu código. Eu vou optar pelo que o @ramaral disse sobre preencher os atributos no construtor e disponibilizar apenas os _getters_